# Where to download gdata objective C client

Tags: objective-c, gdata-api

It seems I can only download the zip files for the [deprecated versions of gdata](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list). Where can i find today's version (as a zip file !)?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can anonymously check out the latest project source code with svn

> svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
>   gdata-objectivec-client-read-only

As mentioned here http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout

Comment: So I have to download each single file ?

Comment: No. Just go in the directory you want to download the source to, check that you have the svn command line tool installed and run that command, it will download all the files in the trunk. If you don't know about svn and git, I strongly suggest you look into it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion

Comment: i have integrate the "Gdata" library into my app now how may i fetch the contact list....

Answer (score 7):

Checkout for google API header files

https://github.com/hoishing/GData-iOS-Static-Library-1.12

1. Add all files (header files and the .a binary image) into your Xcode project
2. In your target -> Build Settings, set /usr/include/libxml2 in Header Search Paths
3. In your target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries, add libxml2.dylib
4. To use the gdata classes, just add the following line in your header file:
   #import "GData.h"
5. Done

Answer (score 1):

you'll also need to add systemConfiguration framework